# How to update the Live Tile with data that changes over time?

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

My Live Tile is tracking the time since 3 types of events: Event1, Event2, Event3. I would like the Live tile to display the time since the events occurred.

I implemented it in a background task like the code below, and I would like to know if it is the right way to do it?

All the examples I saw were with the Run called once and hence the AddTileNotification's are called only once. I modified it to be in a While(true) loop, not sure about that?!

```
using System;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Windows.ApplicationModel.Background;
using Windows.Data.Xml.Dom;
using Windows.Storage;
using Windows.UI.Notifications;


namespace BackgroundTasks
    {    
    public sealed class TileUpdaterClass : IBackgroundTask
        {
        TileUpdater tileUpdater;

        public void Run( IBackgroundTaskInstance taskInstance )
            {
            while ( true )
                {
                BackgroundTaskDeferral deferral = taskInstance.GetDeferral();

                tileUpdater = TileUpdateManager.CreateTileUpdaterForApplication();
                tileUpdater.EnableNotificationQueue( true );

                AddTileNotification( "Since Event1: " + TimeSince( "Event1" ), "tag1", "ms-appx:///Resources/Images/Event1.jpg" );
                AddTileNotification( "Since Event2: " + TimeSince( "Event2" ), "tag2", "ms-appx:///Resources/Images/Event2.jpg" );
                AddTileNotification( "Since Event3: " + TimeSince( "Event3" ), "tag3", "ms-appx:///Resources/Images/Event3.jpg" );

                deferral.Complete();

                Task.Delay( 5000 ); 
                }
            }

        private static string TimeSince( string key )
            {
            TimeSpan since;
            if ( ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values.ContainsKey( key ) )
                {
                since = new TimeSpan( DateTime.Now.Ticks - ( new DateTime( (long)ApplicationData.Current.LocalSettings.Values[ key ] ) ).Ticks );
                }
            return ( since.Hours.ToString( "D2" ) + ":" + since.Minutes.ToString( "D2" ) + ":" + since.Seconds.ToString( "D2" ) );
            }

        private void AddTileNotification( string content, string tag, string image )
            {
            var templateType = TileTemplateType.TileWideSmallImageAndText04;
            var xml = TileUpdateManager.GetTemplateContent( templateType );

            var textNodes = xml.GetElementsByTagName( "text" );
            textNodes[ 0 ].AppendChild( xml.CreateTextNode( "myApp" ) );
            textNodes[ 1 ].AppendChild( xml.CreateTextNode( content ) );

            var imageNodes = xml.GetElementsByTagName( "image" );
            var elt = (XmlElement)imageNodes[ 0 ];
            elt.SetAttribute( "src", image );

            var tile = new TileNotification( xml );
            tile.Tag = tag;


            tileUpdater.Update( tile );
            }
        }
    }
```

I also noticed that the tile is not displaying the 3 events in order. The time is kept correctly but not the order. Is it normal?

Thanks,
EitanB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yes, it's to be expected.  From [Using the notification queue:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/Hh781199.aspx)

> The amount of time each notification in the queue is displayed and the
>   order in which they appear on the tile is based on several internal
>   factors and cannot be controlled by applications.

Comment: Hi Jim,
Thank you for your answer regarding the events order of display.
I would like to ask also if the scheme I used to have the Run routine run for ever, while(true), is the right way to work with the background task and/or the Live Tiles?
Thanks,
Eitan

Comment: well it's pretty close to what [periodic notifications](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jimoneil/archive/2012/08/09/windows-8-notifications-periodic-notifications.aspx) would do for you "out of the box", but periodic notifications don't work on a schedule that aggressive (5 second update), but they don't do that to a large degree because of battery consumption, that's the biggest concern that stands out to me in terms of your implementation, but I don't know what your end goal is.

Comment: Hi Jim, left you a message through your blog. Thx, Eitan

Comment: I'd be reluctant to trying to increase the default 15 minute TimeTrigger via your run loop/Task.Delay. Take a look at the [clock sample](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/Tile-Update-every-minute-68dbbbff) which uses the built-in TimeTrigger but leverages Scheduled Notifications to fill in the interim. This app is in the store now, so the approach would appear to be sound and has passed certification.